# HDD which i installed ubuntu 20.04.1 onto doesn't show up in boot menu

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have a PC with multiple drives.
I burned Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on a pendrive using rufus.
I disconnected everything but the pendrive and only one HDD, the one Ubuntu 20.04.1 be installed onto, to my PC.
It gets installed successfully.
I even watched some youtube and did some other things for a while.
Removed Pendrive and Rebooted.
The HDD wasn't visible in the boot-menu (I use f10 key to launch it at the intel screen) even though it was the only drive connected to PC.
BIOS doesn't detect HDD.
That HDD is, in fact, visible in "Disk Management" section when i boot with Win10, but not in "File Manager".
I have tried reinstalling over a dozen times using various methods available on the internet.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Is this an uefi installation? E.g. boot from your pendrive and start gparted and click View / Device information. It will tell you whether the partition table is gpt or msdos, and whether there is and EFI system partition.

Comment: Tmk, yes It's gpt.

Comment: Is uefi enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: @Seip The destination drive for Ubuntu must have GPT partition scheme to be installed in UEFI mode.The **flash drive** does not need to be GPT, and in fact, having it as GPT can prevent it from booting on some systems. **hotom**: if you did not verify the integrity of your download, or the flash, I recommend re-downloading using the [BitTorrent link](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.1/) if you are not familiar with `sha256sum`. I then suggest flashing it using [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) where it is nearly impossible to choose wrong settings, and will auto-verify the flash.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to update GRUB?

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. It doesn't give me a chance to load it again. I have to find a drive in the boot menu to boot it and update grub. But i can't.

Comment: If you start from your pendrive, then you can 'chroot' (google for this) into your installed system and run grub install and update grub from there.

Comment: @hotom  Just like  on my ubuntu mate 18.04  plug out power source while system is booting  then plug  in again and turn on and  menu  should show again just like on windowses then if first comand dont  work turn on terminal : To open a Terminal window at any time, press Ctrl+Alt+T. A graphical GNOME Terminal window will pop right up. then pdate grub with the following command on any Linux distribution:

sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Comment: See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair